# Angular HTTP Post multiple JSON objects

Tags: angular, for-loop, post, rxjs, httpclient

I am trying to post multiple JSON objects through HTTPClient. I want to send them as one object at a time though, consecutively one after the other. How do I do that?

I am currently mapping through another object array I already have to create a new object array that I want to post. I can successfully console.log the giant object array (86 objects) one by one using the for loop; but I cannot figure out how to http post them one by one.

```
    this.newdailys = this.rooms.map(room => ({ 
      id: null,
      timeCreated0: this.date,
      roomid1: room.id,
      guestwaiting2: null,
      supervisorconfirmed3: null,
      finishedcleaning4: null,
      staffid5: null,
      bathtowelIN6: null,
      bathtowelOUT7: null,
      bathmattIN8: null,
      bathmattOUT9: null,
      sheetSIN10: null,
      sheetSOUT11: null,
      duvetSIN12: null,
      duvetSOUT13: null,
      sheetDIN14: null,
      sheetDOUT15: null,
      duvetDIN16: null,    
      duvetDOUT17: null,
      pillowcaseIN18: null,
      pillowcaseOUT19: null,
      bolstercaseIN20: null,
      bolstercaseOUT21: null,
      sugarIN22: null,
      teaIN23: null,
      coffeeIN24: null,
      creamerIN25: null,
      stirerIN26: null,
      mwaterIN27: null,
      slipperIN28: null,   
      barsoapIN29: null,
      shampooIN30: null,
      dentalkitIN31:null,
      cottonbudIN32: null,
      showercapIN33: null,
      roomtissueIN34: null,
      HBTIN35: null,
      coasterglassIN36: null,
      plastikbeningIN37: null,
      mug238: null,
      electricjug39:null,
      tumblerglass240:null,
      traymerah141: null,
      sugarbowl142: null,
      bedskirting43: null,
      bedpad44: null,
      hanger45:null,
      telpon46: null,
      lamp47: null,
      hairdryer48: null,
      jetshower49: null,
      television50: null,
      underbed51: null,
      timeCompleted52: null,
      deleted53: false,
      }))
      for (let i = 0; i < newdailys.length; i++) {
      return this.http.post(http://localhost:3000/dailys, newdailys[i])}} 

/// what has worked was for (let i = 0; i < newdailys.length; i++) {
      console.log(newdailys[i])}
```

Comment: "How do I do that?" — Depends entirely on how (and *if*) the server side process expects multiple objects to be formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Well this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < newdailys.length; i++) {
      return this.http.post(http://localhost:3000/dailys, newdailys[i])
}
```

will always return after it posts the first object. Your return statement will immediately return to the function caller and abort the for-loop.

Like Quentin already mentioned in his comment, it all depends on how your server side expects them to be formatted. But according to your question I assume, you just want to send each object in a separate post request.

Just remove the return statement inside your for-loop. Of course you want to do something with the responses of your requests. One solution might be to use the 
[rxjs forkJoin operator.](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) And return the resulting observable.

For example you could come up with something like:

```
postObjects(newdailys: any[]) {
    const postObservables: Observable<any>[] = newdailys.map(daily => this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/dailys', daily));
    return forkJoin(...postObservables);
  }
```

But like mentioned above this depends entirely on what you want to do with the results.